# Como atualizar dataGridView ao clicar em um botão?

Tags: c#, ado.net, .net

Estou usando uma interface onde tenho o `menustrip` á esquerda e outro `form` á direita, daí no `menustrip` tem as opções de `novo`(carrega form `nvCli`) e `busca`(carrega form `nvConsCli`), preciso que quando o usuário aperte na opção `busca` ele atualize o `dataGridView` do formulário(`nvConsCli`) que irá abrir, pois caso o usuário tenha acabado de cadastrar um registro ele já aparece na `gridView`

tentei com o seguinte código:

```
nvConsCli.clientesTableAdapter.Fill(nvConsCli.regDataSet.clientes);
```

E outra série de códigos, mas não funciona, ele não recarrega os dados do banco de dados e coloca no `dataGridView`

Answer (score 1):

Crie um método que apenas popula a sua dataGridView, então, no evento do botão buscar, chame esse método no final, para que assim sempre que o evento buscar for executado, o dataGridView será atualizado com os dados. Se puder postar o código posso responder com as devidas alterações.

Answer (score 1):

Assim você garante que cada mudança no DataSet seja automaticamente aplicada no DataGrid :

```
            ... // 1)Carregar seu DataSet 

            // 2) Criar um BindingSource
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(); 

            // 3 ) Relacionar o BS com seu DataSet
            bs.DataSource = idDoSeuDataSet; 

            //4) Relacionar o Grid com seu BindingSource 
            idDoSeuGridView.DataSource = bs;
```

Atualize no evento do Click